# Unity: The type or namespace name 'function' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 3D Unity game and I want to implement a timer. The problem is that I receive the following error in the scirpt:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How to fix the problem?

**The script Timer.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text instruction;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        instruction = GetComponent<Text>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    int timeLeft = 30;

    void Update()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        instruction.text= (timeLeft).ToString();
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
         //   GameOver();
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the inspector It seems that I am not able to assign the specific text field.

[image: Editor View]

[image: Editor View]

Comment: where do you get that error?

Comment: You should probably ask Google what that error means, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
int timeLeft = 30;
timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
```

`Time.deltaTime` is a `float` and `timeLeft` is `int`, you need to convert the float to int before doing the rest.

```
int timeLeft = 30;
timeLeft -= (int)Time.deltaTime;
```

This is what the error means by

> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Yes!

Answer (score 0):

`Time.deltaTime` is a float and you are trying to assign a float  to an integer in `timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime` change `timeLeft` to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

`Time.deltaTime` is a float.

Either Change `timeLeft` to float.

```
float timeLeft=30f;
```

Or Cast as it expects:
`timeLeft-=(int)Time.deltaTime;`